# Биндинг TextBox к одному string в WindowsForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне нужно привязать TextBox к одному string. Нужно чтобы при изменении TextBox строка менялась и наоборот. Пишу вот такой примерно код.

```
someTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", someArray[index].ArrField[otherIndex], "");
```

но почему-то не работает(когда я изменил текст, перешел на следующую запись, произошел ребинд на следующую запись, вернулся назад - а там текст не такой как был до того как перешел на следующую запись). Пробовал последним параметром и пустую строку и null - не работает почему-то. С объектом у которого хотя бы одно поле все работает

```
someTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", someArray[index].ArrField[otherIndex], "FieldName");
```

Пока проблема решилась очень смешно: я создал отдельный класс, в нем одно поле. Все работает, но хотелось бы узнать есть ли нормальное решение. И еще: не знаю имеет ли это значение, но я использую Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: А можно вопрос (чисто так, ради любопытства) - почему Visual Studio 10 используете? Просто часто вижу людей с данной версией и вечно терзает вопрос, почему они не обновляются? Ведь вы так много теряете...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ использую ее только потому что на моей слабой машине не так тормозит как последние версии. Хотя недавно пробовал Visual Studio 2013, вполне нормально работала, но я случайно поставил версию Ultimate на 30 дней и вот недавно срок истек, а кодить срочно надо. 10 студия ставится очень быстро, а новые студии нужно полдня ставить...